# My \usepackage{stata} is giving me an error on LaTeX

Tags: packages, stata

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage{stata}
\title{learning how to use bibtex}
\author{Samia}
\date {\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Intro}
lalalalalla
this is very true (Smith, 1980) but people (Hamed 2011, Andrews 2014) do not believe it ~\cite{AckermanandHeinzerling02}
\section{Conclusions}
\bibliography{CBAcourse}
\bibliographystyle{Chicago}
\end{document}
```

I keep getting an error saying

> *! LaTeX Error: File `stata.sty' not found.*

I have the `stata.sty` package and put the file in the same directory as my LaTeX working file. I am using a Mac.

Please help.

Comment: Simple answer: You don't have the file in the same working directory or anywhere else LaTeX can find it, else it would find it. Welcome to TeX.SX anyway. Sorry that I couldn't be of more help here, but the error message is pretty unambiguous as to what is failing.

Comment: are you starting latex by doing something like `pdflatex /some/path/to/the/file.tex` ? If so stata.sty would need to be in the working directory of the tex process, not the directory with your file. It is simpler to cd to the directory with the file  so these are the same.